# Refresh "hidden" template after login with ajax

Tags: templating, ajax, login

I am trying to create a seamless user login interaction with a modal form using ajax. Let's say I have a navigation template `_navigation.html`

```
<div>
    {% if currentUser %}
    {{ currentUser }}
    — <a href="{{ url('shop/customer') }}">{{ "My Orders"|t }}</a>
    — <a href="{{ url('shop/customer/addresses') }}">{{ "My Addresses"|t }}</a>
    — <a href="{{ url('shop/customer/cards') }}">{{ "My Cards"|t }}</a>
    — <a href="{{ logoutUrl }}">Logout</a>
    {% else %}
      <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">{{ "Login"|t }}</a>
    — <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registerModal">{{ "Register"|t }}</a>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

After successful login I would like to refresh the view by loading the template again (using [jquery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)). Since the template is "hidden" I can't access it. If I make the template "visible" all works, but naturally I would like the template to stay "hidden".

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I would suggest you to create a custom controller that returns the required html together with the login response. Otherwise you would have to do a dirty work around via 2 ajax requests

Comment: Cool, thanks. I will look into custom controllers. What do you mean with 2 ajax requests?

Comment: Some people prefer to now use PHP at all. So a (pretty bad) work around would be to create a second ajax request to your template and insert the result in your container

Comment: Do you think "hidden" template would be accessible via ajax?

Comment: When you create a custom route yes

Comment: But does it only make it accessible via ajax or does it become public? I would assume making a second ajax request is a lot slower then returning html with custom controller in first step?

Comment: It will be public... That's why I always prefer a controller

Comment: OK, thank you. I would recommend you making an answer out of this conversation. If not, I will answer it myself once I'm done with the custom controller and make it work :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77784/discussion-between-krizajb-and-robin-schambach).